# Bash : How to check if all the patterns to check are present in a file in Unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, grep, pattern-matching

I am trying to check if all the patterns given are present in a file .If yes display success .

eg : I have a file like below

```
$ cat test.txt
ABC
123
xyz
ABC
MNO
qwe
$
```

I have the patterns to search are ABC and 123 . So in the above case it should display success .

If my pattern is ABC and 234 it should display FAILURE.

I have tried like below :

```
$ grep -e ABC -e 123 test.txt && echo "SUCCESS" || echo "FAIL"
ABC
123
ABC
SUCCESS
$
$ grep -e ABC -e 234 test.txt && echo "SUCCESS" || echo "FAIL"
ABC
ABC
SUCCESS
$
```

But the above will return success even if one pattern fails also .

Also tried like below . But it will take 2 iteration in the file .

```
$ grep -w "ABC" test.txt && grep -w "123" test.txt && echo "SUCCESS" ||    echo "FAIL"
ABC
ABC
123
SUCCESS
$ grep -w "ABC" test.txt && grep -w "234" test.txt && echo "SUCCESS" ||    echo "FAIL"
ABC
ABC
FAIL
$
```

Any help to achieve this in a single parsing of the file ?

Comment: Basically I wanted to know if AND operation is possible with grep for patterns  .Also what is the most efficient way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use use an `awk` command for doing so:

```
awk -v patt='ABC,123' 'BEGIN {
   n = split(patt, words, /,/)
}
n {
   for (i in words)
      if ($0 ~ "\\<" words[i] "\\>") {
         --n
         delete words[i]
      }
}
END {
   exit n
}' test.txt && echo "SUCCESS" || echo "FAIL"
```

**Explanation:**

- This awk command is passing all the words to search for in a comma split command line argument `patt`
- In the `BEGIN` block we populate an array `words` by splitting the input field and store # of words to search in variable `n`
- When `n > 0` we perform a word search for each element of array in a line and when searched word is found we delete that word from array and decrement `n`
- In the `END` block if exit with the value `n` thus returning `0` (or success) when all the words have been found.

Comment: Doesn't give same behaviour as `-w` flag for grep.

Comment: It seems working .Could you please explain the logic with split command  and overall flow .I am not very familiar with awk

Comment: Also note that if the word contains a `,` then this will fail. You could change the separator to `\\0` in this case though.

Comment: @MathewsJose: Added explanation in answer.

Comment: comma is not considered a word character but if at all there is a possibility of using comma in searched words then an alternate separator like `\0` or \t` or `\n` can be used

Comment: Thanks @anubhava for the explanation . But I didn't get why we have to delete the word from the array . Only the n-- is sufficient right ?

Comment: Ahh .. I got it now @anubhava .. Will there be a way to do the same with grep command . Do grep command support AND operation of patterns ?

Comment: No `grep` command won't be able to handle this requirement. `awk` is the right tool for this.

Answer (score -1):

```
   grep -q 123 fileName && grep -q ABC fileName && echo "Matched" || echo "not matched"
    Matched
    grep -q 123 fileName && grep -q ABQQC fileName && echo "Matched" || echo "not matched"
    not matched
    grep -q 1ZZ23 fileName && grep -q ABC fileName && echo "Matched" || echo "not matched"
    not matched
   grep -q 1ZZ23 fileName && grep -q ABCQQ fileName && echo "Matched" || echo "not matched"
    not matched
```